# List<Object> and List<?>

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

I have two questions, actaully...
First off, Why cant I do this:

```
List<Object> object = new List<Object>();
```

And second, I have a method that returns a `List<?>`, how would I turn that into a `List<Object>`, would I be able to simply cast it?

Thank you!

Comment: Alright, if you guys say that `List<?>` cannot be instantiated, then how is it that the method can return it?

Comment: It's worth noting that `Arrays.asList(T... a)` returns a `List<T>`. You can initialize `List` with `List<Object> li = Arrays.asList(1, 2, "3");` to save some typing, although the returned `List` will be fixed-sized and backed by the array: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Why cant I do this:
>
> ```
> List<Object> object = new List<>();
> ```

You can't do this because [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, and interfaces cannot be instantiated. Only (concrete) classes can be. Examples of concrete classes implementing `List` include [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) etc.

Here is how one would create an instance of `ArrayList`:

```
List<Object> object = new ArrayList<>();
```

> I have a method that returns a `List<?>`, how would I turn that into a `List<Object>`

Show us the relevant code and I'll update the answer.

Comment: The method that returns a `List<?>` is from an external library and I cannot get to the code. I just know that it used to return a `List<Object>`, and then they updated the code and now it returns a `List<?>`, essentially breaking all my coding.

Comment: Answer doesn't adequately address the second part of the question.  How about an example?

Answer (score 6):

```
List<Object> object = new List<Object>();
```

You cannot do this because ***List*** is an interface and you cannot create object of any interface or in other word you cannot instantiate any interface. Moreover, you can assign any object of class which implements **List** to its reference variable. For example you can do this:

```
list<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Here ***ArrayList*** is a class which implements ***List***, you can use any class which implements ***List***.

Answer (score 2):

List is an interface so you can't instanciate it. Use any of its implementatons instead e.g.

```
List<Object> object = new List<Object>();
```

About List :
you can use any object as a generic param for it instance:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

While using `List<Object>` this declaration is invalid because it will be type missmatch.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, yes, you can cast the `List<?>` as a `List<Object>` or a `List<T>` of any type, since the `?` (Wildcard) parameter indicates that the list contains a homogenous collection of an *any* `Object`.  However, there's no way to know at compile what the `type` is since it's part of the exported API only - meaning you can't see what's being inserted into the `List<?>`.

Here's how you would make the cast:

```
List<?> wildcardList = methodThatReturnsWildcardList();
// generates Unchecked cast compiler warning
List<Object> objectReference = (List<Object>)wildcardList;
```

In this case you can ignore the warning because in order for an object to be used in a generic class it must be a subtype of `Object`. Let's pretend that we're trying to cast this as a `List<Integer>` when it actually contains a collection of `String`s.

```
// this code will compile safely
List<?> wildcardList = methodThatReturnsWildcardList();
List<Integer> integerReference = (List<Integer>)wildcardList;

// this line will throw an invalid cast exception for any type other than Integer
Integer myInteger = integerRefence.get(0);
```

Remember: generic types are erased at runtime. You won't know what the collection contains, but you can get an element and call `.getClass()` on it to determine its type.

```
Class objectClass = wildcardList.get(0).getClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TEst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ls=new ArrayList<>();
        ls.add(1);
        ls.add(2);
        List<Integer> ls1=new ArrayList<>();
        ls1.add(3);
        ls1.add(4);
        List<List<Integer>> ls2=new ArrayList<>();
        ls2.add(ls);
        ls2.add(ls1);

        List<List<List<Integer>>> ls3=new ArrayList<>();
        ls3.add(ls2);


        m1(ls3);
    }

    private static void m1(List ls3) {
        for(Object ls4:ls3)
        {
             if(ls4 instanceof List)    
             {
                m1((List)ls4);
             }else {
                 System.out.print(ls4);
             }

        }
    }

}
```